# Using Weld with Liferay 6.1 CE / Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, cdi, jboss-weld

I have this application that I've written as a normal servlet. It uses Weld for CDI. When deploying it on a plain JBoss 7.0.2, everything works just as expected.

I've now converted the application to Portlet 2.0. I try to deploy the portlet to a Liferay 6.1 CE running on JBoss, but I get the following exception

```
14:16:20,587 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-86) 14:16:20,583 ERROR [PortletServlet:97] javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: BeanManager -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.ROOT.ROOT.BeanManager
```

This exception occurs when I call

```
return (BeanManager) new InitialContext()
                .lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a new version of AS7, it contains a fix for Weld usage in a portal environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the production server's deployment environment.

Comment: If you can update the weld jar to a new version that may work for you, otherwise you're stuck.

Comment: I've now tried both approaches. I was unable to deploy Liferay on JBoss 7.1 - some errors occurred that I was unable to solve. I then tried upgrading Weld to 1.1.5.AS71.Final (git tag) by doing this: sources from https://github.com/weld/core -- "mvn clean install -Pupdate-jboss-as" updates the AS7;
see jboss-as/jboss-as-7/build.properties for jboss.home prop

This updated the weld jar files, but I keep having the exactly same problem as I stated in original post.